# Where to get an IBM jre for 64-bit Windows?

Tags: windows, java

I couldn't find anything from IBM website about where to download an IBM jre (specifically, IBM jre1.6.0 J9 2.4 SR6) for a 64-bit Windows OS.  Google takes me to a link which looks similar, but that jre would only work on an IBM product, I assume their own server/workstation or something like that.

Comment: Why can't you get the regular JRE for Windows?

Comment: And why do you want that exact version?

Comment: Same as [cross-post on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/166860/where-to-get-ibm-jre-for-a-64-bit-windows-os).  One should be closed.

Comment: the reason I need a IBM jre is for testing purpose. I am trying to replicate the exact customer environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM doesn't consider its JVM to be a product in its own right. It's seen as a supporting technology, a common underpinning, that is used to implement actual products like WebSphere Application Server or Lotus Connections. This is why it can be hard to find information about the JVM specifically, and to the best of my knowledge (which, however, may very well be wrong) it is not formally offered for separate download.

Your customer probably obtained it as part of an IBM product, for example if they're implementing applications in WAS then they're programming against the IBM JVM. It's possible they could also have copied it out of the internals of a product, maybe even a trial download of a product, but that is likely to be pretty dubious from a licensing point of view.

Pete

Answer (score 5):

IBM dont like to call a JDK a JDK, they call it "IBM Development Package for Eclipse".

You can get it here

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/eclipse/

There the JDK is "part of a product" that is designed for developing Java applications.  i.e. its a Java Developer Kit with a confusing name.

Be warned, the above address is the start of a trail of registration and clicks, littered with please spam me checkboxes, that eventually leads you to an HTTP download that is 300Mb in size only about 100Mb of which probably interests you.

Answer (score 2):

There is more universal entry point into IBM Java world.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/
It shows both current and also future Java releases which might be of interest to some.

For an answer specific to the posted question teknopaul is right on.